# Override ComboBox Template without theme

Tags: wpf, combobox, controltemplate

I added the `ComboBox` default `ControlTemplate` (copied from Blend) to the `ResourceDictionary` of a `UserControl` so I could override the `ComboBox` `ControlTemplate`. When I added the `ControlTemplate` I had to add the following xml namespace:

```
xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
```

There are three references in the comboBox default template to objects that are defined in the theme of the PresentationFramework

```
<Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome ... >
<Microsoft_Windows_Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome ... > 
<Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome ... >
```

Is there a way to remove these classes yet allow the system theme to add them at runtime (as it usually does)? So we don't have to have a hard coded theme in this user control.

**Edit:** I understand these are not wrappers. However they are pointers to the theme. How to I dynamically pick the theme with just a place holder at compile-time?

Comment: Luks difficult if you have **used** `ButtonChrome` or `SystemDropShadowChrome` etc as part of your custom template. If you remove the aero reference or even the individual chrome classes, your template code wont compile! `DynamicResources` and missing classes referred in a template are totally different concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the 'mwt' namespace if you use one of these classes in your template. The compiler will complain during compilation. Although the assembly is called the Aero theme, I think you can use these classes on Windows XP without any problems. It's not a wrapper around the Aero controls, but it's a WPF implementation of the look & feel of Windows Vista/7 controls.